# PHP Google MAPS - API (cannot echo)

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I am trying to get some information from coordinate via google geocode api.

My PHP code was:

```
$lat="54.1456123";
$long = "10.413456";

$adgetg = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$long&sensor=false");
$address = json_decode($adgetg);
echo $address->short_name;
```

And full array was:

```
stdClass Object ( [results] => Array ( 
         [0] => stdClass Object ( [address_components] => Array ( 
                [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                       [long_name] => Prinzeninsel 
                       [short_name] => Prinzeninsel 
                       [types] => Array ( 
                                 [0] => route )
                       )
                [1] => stdClass Object ( 
                       [long_name] => Plön 
                       [short_name] => Plön 
                       [types] => Array ( 
                                 [0] => locality 
                                 [1] => political )
                       )
                )
          )
       )
```

When i try use `echo $address->short_name;` i get error 
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$short_name

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data from Google is an *Object* containing an *Array* of *Objects* , so you need to structure your request more specifically.

```
$address->$results[0]->$address_components[0]->short_name

 ^^^^      ^^^^^  ^^        ^^^^          ^^^      ^^^^
Object     Array  ^^        ^^^^         Array     ^^^^
           Key   (Object)   ^^^^          Key      ^^^^
                            Array       (Object)  Property
```

The above will return the `short_name` prooperty of the object sitting in results array placement 0 (the *first* element).

If you use the `print_r` or `var_dump` output of the JSON object you shuold be able to easily destinguise the access route (illustrated above) to reach the element you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
foreach($address->results as $value)
{
    foreach($value as $val)
    {
        if (is_array($val) || is_object($val))
        {
            foreach($val as $v)
            {
                if(isset($v->short_name))
                print_r($v->short_name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get output
PrinzeninselPlönPlönSHDE24306PlönPlönSHDE24306RathjensdorfPlönSHDEPlönSHDESHDEDE

Comment: These are the values associated with key "short_name". That's what you wanted to retrieve, Right?

Comment: Can i get just Prinzeninsel ?

Comment: That you can get using following code: echo $address->results[0]->address_components[0]->short_name;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$address = json_decode($adgetg);
```

Use

```
$address = json_decode($adgetg, true);
```

Doing this you will get an array instead of `stdClass Object`.

```
$lat="54.1456123";
$long = "10.413456";

$adgetg = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$long&sensor=false");
$address = json_decode($adgetg, true);
echo $address['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['short_name'];
```

OR use this

```
echo $address->results[0]->address_components[0]->short_name;
```